# Is it possible to use config server to set the default timezone?

Tags: spring-boot, timezone, application.properties, spring-cloud-config-server

I am trying to use config server to set the default timezone for the application.

I have tried putting below value in VM argument and its working. `-Duser.timezone=IST`

However, when I am adding the property `user.timezone` to `application.properties` or `bootstrap.properties` or config server properties, it's not working.

Other thing I tried was using a `@PostConstruct` like below:

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
```

But here I am hardcoding the timezone information and I need it to be configurable.

I believe application might need this property in the very beginning of the application startup and thus, properties file settings are not working but I am not sure.

Is there any workaround or solution by which I can use config server to set the Default timezone to spring boot application?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time zone in the main method, but I don't know if this is enough configurable for your means.

```
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
...
```

Notice that setting the default time zone in the post construct allows to previous beans to get the previous time zone instead of yours. Change it at the begining to avoid this issue.

Comment: I am finally reading it from properties files and using it the way you mentioned.